# PHP SOAP stdclass object array

Tags: php, arrays, soap

I am using PHP SOAP script to retrieve data from a web service. My PHP code shown below results in a stdclass object which includes an array called `Staff`.

```
    $values = $client->GetAllStaff($search_query);
        
    $xml = $values->SasReqRespGetAllStaff;
    
    print "<pre>\n";
    print_r($xml);
    print "</pre>";
?>
```

This produces the following result on in my web browser.

> ```
>   "stdClass Object
>   (
>    [Source] => R5 Sim
>    [RespMsgTag] => 5
>    [RespAck] => OK
>    [RespNote] => 
>    [TotalItems] => 13
>    [Staff] => Array
>       (
>        [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [StaffID] => 15
>               [Last] => LastName1
>               [First] => TESTstaffOut1
>               [Middle] => MName1
>               [Role] => Level 1
>           )
>        [1] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [StaffID] => 16
>               [Last] => LastName2
>               [First] => TESTstaffOut2
>               [Middle] => MName2
>               [Role] => Level 2
>           )"
> ```

How can I write the values from [Staff] => Array into PHP variables, which can be used later and/or for other PHP? How can I loop through Staff [0], [1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are already in PHP variables (contained within the stdClass object).  However if you want to loop through them you can do so like this:

```
foreach($xml->Staff as $staff)
{
  // Eg: To get the staff id:
  $staffId = $staff->StaffID;
  var_dump($staffId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! Is this how I would put the Staff stdclass obect into a MySql database?

Comment: Basically, yes. This will allow you to query the data. The other way is that you could serialize it and store it in the db that way (not queryable)

Answer (score 0):

I used the information above and came up with the following, tested and working.

```
echo " <br> Available Groups <table> <tr><th>Group ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Middle Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Role</th></tr>";
    foreach($xml->Staff as $staff )
    {
        $staffId = $staff->StaffID;
        $lastName = $staff->Last;
        $firstName = $staff->First;
        $middleName = $staff->Middle;
        $role = $staff->Role;

        $html = "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".$staffId."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$firstName."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$middleName."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$lastName."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$role."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";
        echo $html;
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

I also used information from the following post.
[iterating through a stdClass object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287782/iterating-through-a-stdclass-object-in-php)